# Having problem with Binary Search Tree insertion,It is working fine for left tree but not for right

Tags: tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, insertion

> This is the insertion function I am using.Root creation and insertion as a left child working fine.But insertion as right child happening only twice.

```
struct node * insert(struct node *root1, struct node *new1)
{    printf("root address=%u",root1);

    if(root1==NULL){
            printf("xyz");
        root1=new1;
    return root1;
    }
  if(root1->data>new1->data)
    {
        if(root1->lchild==NULL){
            root1->lchild=new1;
            printf("A1");
        }
        else{
                printf("A2");
            insert(root1->lchild,new1);

        }

    }
    if(root1->data < new1->data)
    {
        if(root1->rchlid==NULL){
            root1->rchlid=new1;
            printf("B1");
        }
        else{
                printf("B2");
          insert(root1->rchlid,new1);

        }

    }
    printf("FFF");
  return root;
}
```

Comment: Use the return value, Luke!

Comment: Where to use sir

Comment: Also: `root1 != root` (root is never defined)

Answer (score 0):

Simplified:

---

```
struct node * insert(struct node *zroot, struct node *new1)
{    
    if(zroot==NULL) return new1;

    if (zroot->data>new1->data) zroot->lchild = insert(zroot->lchild,new1);
    else zroot->rchild = insert(zroot->rchild,new1);

    return zroot;
}
```

Comment: sir I have used this code but the problem persists .